# Does a Canadian Equifax credit report have one's age on it?

Tags: canada, credit-card, credit-report

I have never got a credit report before and I want to know whether it includes age because I need to show it to rent a place but I'm not comfortable with anybody knowing my age. Credit reports from Equifax just have the credit score...and what else really?

Comment: If it does have your age or date of birth, couldn't you just black out that section?

Answer (score 1):

Per the below link, it does appear that age shows up on a Canadian Equifax Credit Report.

http://www.fcac-acfc.gc.ca/Eng/resources/publications/creditLoans/Pages/Understa-Comprend-0.aspx

Comment: Here's some more information about requesting a free credit report, to see for yourself what is on you report.  http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/how-to-check-your-credit-report-1.1185975

Comment: Free takes time. Real estate is competitive here! Lost so many properties due to not sending in the application fast enough.

Comment: Looks like you can pay about 30 bucks to get the information immediately.